# Bibliographical Index

Tags: biblatex, authorindex

I am using memoir and biblatex-chicago (with biber).

I would like to add a bibliographical index, so as to indicate the pages on which a certain work is referenced after each entry in the bibliography (as shown here: http://www.press.uchicago.edu/books/HOC/HOC_V2_B3/HOC_VOLUME2_Book3_bbl_index.pdf)

I tried the authorindex package, but nothing happens. Here is the setup.

```
\documentclass[12pt, openany]{memoir}

\usepackage{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
\usepackage[miniindex]{authorindex}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\mainmatter

\printauthorindex
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: Probably better to use `biblatex`'s own indexing facilities, which you can enable with one of the following options `indexing=true|cite|bib`. I also have to ask: are you running `makeindex`?  ... However, if sounds like you might actually be after what is called 'backref' in LaTeX circles. This is enabled with `backref=true` and further controlled with `backrefstyle=<option>`.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this will help you get started. It includes the basics to get 'back references' to the page where the reference was cited and how to index the citations. These two tasks serve similar purposes, but are not the same.

\documentclass[12pt, openany]{memoir}

```
% recommended packages when using biblatex
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[strict]{csquotes}

\usepackage[
backend=biber,
hyperref,
% These lines affect the bibliography:
backref,
backrefstyle=three, % = default
% This line affects the index and requires `makeindex <filename>.idx`
indexing=true, % other options: false (default) | cite | bib
]{biblatex-chicago}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}% file ships with biblatex package
%\usepackage[miniindex]{authorindex}

\usepackage{hyperref}

% turn on indexing
\makeindex

\begin{document}

\cite{loh}
\cite{geer}
\cite{worman}
\cite{wilde}
\cite{nussbaum}
\cite{massa}
\cite{kullback}

\newpage
% \cite{loh}
% \cite{geer}
% \cite{worman}
% \cite{wilde}
\cite{nussbaum}
\cite{massa}
\cite{kullback}

\newpage
\cite{loh}
\cite{geer}
\cite{worman}
\cite{wilde}
\cite{nussbaum}
\cite{massa}
\cite{kullback}

\newpage
\cite{loh}
\cite{geer}
\cite{worman}
\cite{wilde}
% \cite{nussbaum}
% \cite{massa}
% \cite{kullback}

\newpage
%\cite{loh}
\cite{geer}
\cite{worman}
\cite{wilde}
\cite{nussbaum}
\cite{massa}
%\cite{kullback}

\printindex
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Please note that the **Index** is generated by means of the `makeindex` program. You must add it to the compilation sequence; e.g.,

```
latex     filename.tex
biber     filename.bcf
makeindex filename.idx
latex     filename.tex
latex     filename.tex
```

Every time you `\cite` a new work, you will need to re-run the above sequence of commands.

Of course, many TeX-aware editors know about `makeindex`, too. So you should consult the instructions for yours to make sure it knows to run `makeindex` as needed.